# How can I have two different return types in my Java method?

Tags: java, generics, methods, merge

I have two very similar methods and I would like to merge them (with the help of generics). However, they have different return types. What can I do?

```
    public static <A, B> A veggie(MyList <Box<A, B>> b, int j) {

        A veggieA = b.head.first;
        return veggieA;
    }

    public static <A, B> B veggie2(MyList <Box<A, B>> b, int j) {

        B veggieB = b.head.second;
        return veggieB;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't distinguish by return type alone in Java 7.  Java 6 had a bug which allowed you to do this but I wouldn't recommend using it.

This means you can't merge them without making the return type `Object` or doing an unchecked cast which is not a good idea.

In your example, I would make the method names different so it is clear that you will get the first or the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two methods having same name and same parameters.

See [Method Overloading](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=284).

[Java overloading rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901259/java-overloading-rules)

[Java overloading and inheritance rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110631/java-overloading-and-inheritance-rules)

Comment: they don't have the same name: veggie & veggie2!

Comment: on what condition you'll decide that when it should return `A` and when `B`?

Answer (score 0):

- You can't declare that a method can return type X or type Y, unless
  either X or Y is a supertype of the other (in which case other
  subtypes could be returned, too)
- You can't declare two methods which differ only in return type

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return type of the method to a common class that are both used by `A` and `B`. But, assuming both `A` and `B` extend `Base` you can use this:

```
public static BaseClass veggie(MyList <Box<A, B>> b, int j) {
    BaseClass veggie;
    // Do things
    return veggie;
}
```

As you want to merge both methods, I suppose that `A` and `B` have some common grounds. If this is not the case, you can use the `Object` class as return type.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method return type to object . Using `instanceof` operator you can differentiate.

**Example**

```
public static Object veggie(MyList <Box<A, B>> b, int j) {
    if(some_condition){
        A veggieA = b.head.first;
        return veggieA;
    }else{
        B veggieB = b.head.second;
        return veggieB;
    }
}

.
.
.

Object  obj=veggie(b,j);
if (obj instanceof <A, B> A) {
    do something    
else{
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case classes A and B would have to implement the same interface, e.g. C.
When A and B implement C you can write:

```
public static <C, A extends C, B extends C> C veggie1(MyList <Box<A, B>> b, int j) {
  C veggieA = b.head.first;
  return veggieA;
}

public static <C, A extends C, B extends C> C veggie2(MyList <Box<A, B>> b, int j) {
  C veggieB = b.head.second;
  return veggieB;
}
```

So if you wanna merge them now you need to pass a parameter to the method that specifies whether you want first or second.

for example:

```
public static <C, A extends C, B extends C> C veggie(MyList <Box<A, B>> b, int j, boolean first) {
  C veggie;
  if (first) 
    veggie = b.head.first;
  else 
    veggie = b.head.second;
  return veggie;
}
```