# Method overloading and inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I have the following program but it wont compile:

```
public class A {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println ("bla");
    }
}

class AX extends A {

    public void method(int a) {
        System.out.println ("Blabla");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a2 = new AX();
        a2.method(5);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't a2.method(5) use the subclasses method? Isn't this method overloading?

Comment: `a2.method(5)` will _definitely_ call the subclass's method, since there is no method with a matching signature in `A`.

Comment: Object A doesn't know who method(int) is. . .

Comment: It will not call the method of `AX`. `a2` has only the visibility of methods from class `A`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java overloading and inheritance rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110631/java-overloading-and-inheritance-rules)

Answer (score 1):

Only methods of class `A` are visible to the compiler. This is because your Object `a2` is of type `A` according to `A a2 = new AX();`. If you change this line to `AX a2 = new AX();` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you confuse terms `overloading` and `overriding`.

`Overloading` is adding a different method with same name as existing one, that differs in input parameters and return type. It has nothing to do with inheritance. From the inheritance point of view overloading is just adding a new method. Your class `A` has no idea, what it's successors new methods are.

`Overriding` is replacing a method with a different implementation. `A` knows that there exists a method, therefore you can change it in it's successor `AX`.

You have two possibilities. Either define `public void method(int a)` in `A`:

```
public class A {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println ("bla");
    }

    public void method(int a) {
        System.out.println ("Blabla from A");
    }
}
```

or use AX

```
AX a2 = new AX();
a2.method(5);
```

because the only class, that knows about the `public void method(int a)` is `AX`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java visibility determined by `Object type`, not by `Reference type`.

In your case:

```
A a2 = new AX();

Object type A, so compiler can't find method(int a);
```