# Calling overloaded inherited methods using super class reference

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, syntax, overloading

I do not understand this Java behavior. I have two classes:

```
class C1 {
    public void m1(double num) {
        System.out.println("Inside C1.m1(): " + num);
    }
}

class C2 extends C1 {
    public void m1(int num) {
        System.out.println("Inside C2.m1(): " + num);
    }
}
```

And it is my main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C1 c = new C2();
        c.m1(10);
    }
}
```

And the result was:

```
Inside C1.m1(): 10.0
```

When I expected:

```
Inside C2.m1(): 10
```

Also when I try to complete the code syntax, I found this:

[image]

Where is the other m1 of C2 class?

I also check the bytecode of my Main.class and I saw this:

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class com.company.Main {
  public com.company.Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class com/company/C2
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method com/company/C2."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: ldc2_w        #4                  // double 10.0d
      12: invokevirtual #6                  // Method com/company/C1.m1:(D)V
      15: return
}
```

The bytecode tell me that it will invoke the C1.m1 (D)V (line 12).

Why the method of C1? I am trying to understand this behavior.

Comment: Note that adding `@Override` to the second m1 will stop this from happening IRL :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java overloading and inheritance rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110631/java-overloading-and-inheritance-rules)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your two methods named `m1` do not have the same signature; the one in the superclass takes a `double`, and the one in the subclass takes an `int`. This means that the compiler will select the method signature to call based on the compile-time type of your variable, which is `C1`, and will call `m1(double)`. Since at runtime the class `C2` doesn't have an overriding version of `m1(double)`, the version from `C1` is invoked.

The rule is that method *signatures* are computed at compile time based on compile-time types; method calls are *dispatched* at runtime based on matching signatures.

Comment: so, I have to do a mandatory cast? or create `C2 c = new C2();`

Comment: @Rob3 This question doesn't explain that the method `m1` in `C2` is overloaded and not `overriden`. See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Rob3 You'll have to do one or the other to invoke `m1(int)`. Something to change the compile-time type of the target to `C2`.

Comment: The question title say overloading behavior not override

Answer (score 9):

It's because of the parameters. The method you call is a method with a double parameter. m1 inside of C2 is not overriding this, instead it's overLOADING it.

If you want to call m1 in C2, you have to cast the reference such that the compiler accepts what you're doing.

Comment: That's what the OP says. he is overloading the method.

Comment: he is expecting the over**loaded** method to be called? I don't think hes that dumb

Comment: I try to call the other method but it not appears.. also I thing that C2 have two method first: `m1(double)` and second: `m1(int)` When I called m1(10) and expected that `m1(int )` will be invoked.

Comment: To call the otherr method, you have to cast the object, example code: `((C2)c).m1(10);`

Comment: @Rob3 read the answer from SRobertz. The method visible to you depend on the variable TYPE and not the actual object.

Comment: The other method is called because of automatic type conversation

Comment: @Alboz thats what I'm saying. If he wants the other method to be called, he has to cast the object.

Comment: Distjubo you have to be more precise. What happens is that at compile time the compiler sees only the method with Double signature, then it changes 10 to 10.0. At runtime the method with double is chosen because 10.0 is a double. Include this in your answer dont talk about overriding.

Comment: @Alboz If you are that smart, why don't you open your own answer? Also you could edit my answer.

Comment: @Distjubo The only way to call `m1(int)` is to use a reference to `C2`. Casting just doesn't make sense. Can you elaborate on what you mean by `he has to cast the object`?

Comment: @bot thats not correct. This code ( `((C2)c).m1(10);`) does work.

Comment: @Distjubo That's casting the reference, not the object.

Comment: yes, but in fact, the method m1 in C2 is getting called. Thats what the OP wanted to have. sorry about that confusion. and btw, you can also use the edit function!

Answer (score 8):

The reason why you see the output as `Inside C1.m1(): 10.0` and not `Inside C1.m1(): 10` or `Inside C2.m1(): 10.0` is because :

1. You are not overriding the method `m1` in `C2`. You are overloading the `m1(doube)` method that you inherited from `C1` to `m1(int)` instead.
2. The `C2` class now has two `m1` methods. One that is `inherited` from `C1` and has the signature `m1(double)` and one that is overloaded in `C2` and has the signature `m1(int)`
3. When the compiler sees the call `c.m1(10)`, it resolves this call based on the reference type. Since the reference type is `C1`, the compiler is going to resolve this call to `m1(double)` in `C1`.
4. At runtime, the JVM is going to resolve the call to `m1(double)` in `C2` which is the method inherited from `C1`. (As explained in point 2)

There are two ways in which the `m1(int)` method can be called :

`((C2)c).m1(10);`

**OR**

`C2 c = new C2();
c.m1(10);`

Answer (score 6):

Java does method dispatch on static types, and your variable `c` is of type `C1`, so `m1(int)` is not visible, and your `10` is cast to `double`.

Comment: this seems the shortest and best answer to me.

Comment: This answer is the simplest explanation. In general, it would not be correct to call m1(int) on a C1 object, even if the instance is a C2, because in general objects of type C1 do not have such a method.

Answer (score 4):

Method signatures for both methods are different.

```
public void m1(double num) 
public void m1(int num)
```

So there is no overriding in this case. Now when you say

```
    C1 c = new C2();
    c.m1(10);
```

at compile time, it will se reference is of type `C1` which has method `public void m1(double num)` which is compatible with 10 [int in expanded to double]. So int is promoted to double, and the corresponding method is called (which is also what you see in the bytecodes).

Answer (score 3):

If you call c.m1(10.0) it will call the method of the ancestor as you were expecting at first.

You're doing method overloading in your example (that is adding more methods with the same name and different signature) instead of method overriding (that is changing the implementation of an ancestor's method at a descendent by redeclaring it with the same signature, AKA same name and same type of result and of method arguments - argument names shouldn't matter).

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your code, you are not taking advantage of inheriting to get the answer you want. You have to change this line

```
C1 c = new C2();
```

to

```
C2 c = new C2();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see methods of C2, because you instance variable is declared as C1 and also because they don't have the same signature. You have double parameter in one method and in second a int type which makes them for JVM completely different methods (so no inheritance will work here).

So if you have int type in C1 method then you need to have also int type in C2 method, then JVM will run method from C2 like you wanted.

Also you can cast variable to C2 type then you will be able to access to methods of C2.

Answer (score 1):

Since `C1.m1(double num)` is a public method, it inherited C2. So your C2 also has a method, `m1(double num)`, and that's why it is called. From `main()` you actually called `C2.m1(double num)`.

**Note**: Now at class `C2` you have two overloaded methods - 
`m1(int num)` and `m1(double num)`. And `C2.m1(int num)` is a different method from `C2.m1(double num)`.

Answer (score 0):

Java chooses the most specific applicable type. In this case m1(int) is not applicable.
   Emphasis on the reference of class that hold object of same class(c1) or an object of any sub classes of class(c2) &  method name and parameter list .

Your method with double parameters is being called because double takes priority over int. This is because an int can be assigned to a double, but not the other way around.

So there are so many things to be consider at the (run) time of method call.

Yes for ur case your main class should be like this

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            C1 c = new C2();
            c.m1(10);
            ((C2) c).m1(10);
    //or
            C2 cobj = new C2();
            cobj.m1(10);
        }


**OutPut**
Inside C1.m1(): 10.0
Inside C2.m1(): 10
Inside C2.m1(): 10
```